# Get variable from component which I navigated to inside of router.events.subscribe

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am creating application history functionality and need to grab a variable from each component that is gotten from an http call when each component initializes.

Currently I am just subscribing to router.events inside of my AppComponent like so

```
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private router: Router, private historyService: HistoryService) {
        this.router.events
            .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
            .subscribe((routerEvent) => {
                console.log('Storing History Entry: ', routerEvent);
                this.historyService.saveEntry(routerEvent);
            });
    }
}
```

Is there a way for me to get a variable from each component under this and pass it through to the history service so that the history can include this variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a fixed value, you can use the data property on the route configuration to provide a bit of data with each route.

```
{
    path: 'products',
    data: { someBitofInfo: 'info'},
    component: 'ProductComponent'
},
```

The data property is read-only so you can only use it for fixed values. But you can define a different fixed value for each path.

OR

If that is not an option (the data is not fixed) then you could add the name to the URL as an optional or query parameter ... the downside of that is that it will show up in the address bar. But if you don't care what your address bar URL looks like, then it would be an option for you.

Comment: Ya unfortunately I'm actually using a unique id in from the uri to fetch that object's information so it is not fixed for each path.

Comment: If its on the URL, then just pull it from the URL. You have access to the URL when subscribing to router events.

Comment: It's a number in the url which I have access to, and I need to use that number get the name of that object from the service. The number is a unique identifier but the name may not be unique. I'm thinking to just make the call from the history service again, I was just hoping to use the value that was already in the component instead of making another call.

Comment: You could add the name to the URL as an optional or query parameter ... the downside of that is that it will show up in the address bar. But if you don't care what your address bar URL looks like, then it would be an option for you.

Comment: Nice! great idea, I don't care about the url since this will be a mobile application (using Cordova) and the address bar is not visible. What's the protocol for selecting an answer that's in the comments?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a shared service among the components and use that service property:

```
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private router: Router, private historyService: HistoryService) {
        this.router.events
            .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
            .subscribe((routerEvent) => {
                console.log('Storing History Entry: ', routerEvent);
                this.historyService.saveEntry( this.shared.service.getMyVar());
);
            });
    }
}
```

or even call getMyVar directly from the historyService.

**shared service**

```
myVar:any;
getMyVar(){
 return this.MyVar;
}
setMyVar(value){
 this.myVar=value;
}
```

**components**

```
this.sharedService.setMyVar(value)
```

An other solution would be the use of local storage, but it has the constraint in case the user disabled the local storage

Comment: Good idea, but it looks like we aren't guaranteed timing between the router events and the component lifecycle hooks. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17473